# How to handle outdated DS-160 form and scheduling a new appointment for a US B1/B2 visa

Tags: visas, us-visa

Today is June 11th, 2023, and I have already submitted my DS-160 form online for a US B1/B2 visa application. However, my appointment in Madrid, Spain is scheduled for June 6th, 2024, and there are no earlier appointment slots available. This creates two concerns for me:

1. If there are changes in my job or personal circumstances during the one-year gap, my DS-160 form will not reflect the updated information, and I am unable to edit it. Has anyone faced a similar situation, and what options would be available in such cases?
2. If I decide to schedule a fresh appointment and generate a new DS-160 form (AAXXXXXXXX), what happens if I do not submit it immediately? Can I submit it closer to the appointment date, say, two weeks before? I've read online that DS-160 forms should be submitted within 30 days of creation, or they are deleted. Is this information accurate?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or experiences from individuals who have encountered similar circumstances. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote to their support and got the response as:

Dear Visa Applicant,

Applicants must fill out a DS-160 online visa application form completely and correctly at https://ceac.state.gov/genniv/ before scheduling a visa appointment.

The DS-160 barcode number can now be updated up to one time without having to cancel the existing appointment. If you need to update the DS-160 confirmation number, please follow the steps below:

1. Log into your account at https://ais.usvisa-info.com
2. In the "Applicant Summary Page", click on the "gear" icon and select "Edit"
3. Update the "DS-160 Number" field with the complete and correct confirmation number
4. Click "Save"
5. Attend your appointment on the scheduled date and time

If you bring a DS-160 visa application form to your interview that is different from the DS-160 confirmation number entered in the appointment system, your application may not be accepted, and applicants will have to schedule a new appointment based on regular appointment availability.

Sincerely,
The Contact Desk Support Team

I have tried these steps myself and they work perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: It might be a good idea to add how early before the scheduled appointment should the DS-160 be updated. I know from personal experience that US consulate officers review DS-160 forms for upcoming appointments in advance.