# DS-160 expired before the VAC appointment

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I applied for B1/B2 visa application for my parents last year.

I had filled the DS 160 form completely but forgot to submit it. Meanwhile, I was able to book a appointment slot for interview in April 2024.

I am now unable to retrieve the DS 160 form. What are my possible options?

1. Should I cancel the appointments and start from scratch by applying for fresh DS 160 and then trying my luck for appointments?
2. Is it possible to somehow fill a new DS 160 form and update this information in the interview appointment confirmation page?

Please provide some insights.

Update: I noticed a [post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/181690/how-to-handle-outdated-ds-160-form-and-scheduling-a-new-appointment-for-a-us-b1?rq=1) where the person was able to update the new DS 160 number in the appointment confirmation page, however the website he has mentioned doesn't have India in the list of countries.